# vb.net searching access database returns date error when using #

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, oledbcommand

I've been struggling to figure this one out, and keep running into the same issue.  I have an Access database that has linked Excel Files.  The title of the excel file is Store # and the pound symbol is where I'm running into issues.

```
New OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM LSM WHERE Store # = @Store", myConnection)
    lstscmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Store", CInt(gateDBSearch))
```

If I remove the # symbol, and remove it in my code it works (The richtexbox shows only the result for the record searched), unfortunately this isn't an option in the final version.  If I leave the # symbol in the file, but remove it from the code, the richtextbox fills with all of the results.  If I leave the # symbol on both the code and file I get a Syntax error in date in query expression 'Store # = @Store' exception.  Any help on this would be great.

```
Dim lstscmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM LSM WHERE Store # = @Store", myConnection)
        lstscmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Store", CInt(gateDBSearch))
        dr = lstscmd.ExecuteReader
        While dr.Read()

            txtRichInfo.AppendText(dr("Gate Tech").ToString + Environment.NewLine)
            lblAccessSysChange.Text = dr("Access System").ToString

        End While

        myConnection.Close()
        lblAccessSysChange.Visible = True
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your field name contains special characters, you need to wrap it in square brackets to tell the SQL parser that it's all one name.

Comment: Thank you so much!  A co-worker and I kept on trying every different thing and couldn't get it to work.  This worked perfectly!